# How to control the when calling parallelStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have following simple code to demonstrate the usage of `parallelStream`,

```
int reducedParallel = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).parallelStream()
    .reduce(10, (a, b) -> a + b, (a, b) -> {
       System.out.println("i am called");
       return a + b;
    });
```

The value of `reducedParallel`  is 36 and the message `i am called` is printed twice.

So, each element 1,2,3 is executed separately(with parallism 3)

I would ask how to control the parallism when calling parallelStream,

eg, I would like 1 and 2 are run together in one parallism, and 3 is another parallesim(with parallism 2),
So that , `reducedParallel` will be 26, and `i am called` only prints once.

Comment: See https://kamilszymanski.github.io/controlling-parallelism-level-of-java-parallel-streams/.

Comment: It's dangerous to rely of ordering of operations when executed concurrently. You'll find it difficult to avoid brittle and non-deterministic functionality.

Comment: Why do you want that? You _can_ influence the number of workers as Sweeper has noted,  but if you want fine-grained control over how those threads perform the task, the streams API probably isn't the tool you're looking for.

Also, that's a nasty use of "reduce", because the output varies depending on the number of threads due to the use of "10" (not an arithmetic identity) as the identity value.

Answer (score -1):

Split your original stream on separate sub-streams and then handle these batches in parallel:

```
Stream<Integer> source = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
Function<Integer, String> concurrencyClassifier =
    it -> it == 1 || it == 2 ? "t1" : "t2";

Integer result = source.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    concurrencyClassifier
)).values().stream().parallel().map(it ->
    it.stream().reduce(10, Integer::sum, Integer::sum)
).reduce(0, Integer::sum, Integer::sum);

System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Output:

```
Result: 26
```